# Implement the click on a recycleviwer item that has been grouped into a hashmap?

Tags: android

I have a list that is grouped by the dates and after doing so, is sent to the adapter, so that the layout is assembled.
Listing code:

```
agendamentoVos = (ArrayList<AgendamentoVo>) ((RetornoFilaAtendimento) asyncTaskResult.getResult()).getRetorno();
            HashMap<Date, List<AgendamentoVo>> groupedHashMap = groupDataIntoHashMap(agendamentoVos);

            for (Date date : groupedHashMap.keySet()) {
                DateItem dateItem = new DateItem();
                String date1 = "";
                try {
                    date1 = UtilDateFormat.formatDateToStringAnoMesDia(date);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                dateItem.setDate(date1);
                listItem.add(dateItem);

                for (AgendamentoVo pojoOfJsonArray : groupedHashMap.get(date)) {
                    GeneralItem generalItem = new GeneralItem();
                    generalItem.setAgendamentoVoGeneral(pojoOfJsonArray);//setBookingDataTabs(bookingDataTabs);
                    listItem.add(generalItem);
                }
            }
```

Here grouping method:

```
private HashMap<Date, List<AgendamentoVo>> groupDataIntoHashMap(List<AgendamentoVo> agendamentoVoList) {

    HashMap<Date, List<AgendamentoVo>> groupedHashMap = new HashMap<>();

    for (AgendamentoVo agendamentoVo : agendamentoVoList) {

        Date hashMapKey = UtilDateFormat.removeHora(agendamentoVo.getItemAgenda().getDtConsulta());// dd/MM/yyyy

        if (groupedHashMap.containsKey(hashMapKey)) {
            // The key is already in the HashMap; add the pojo object
            // against the existing key.
            groupedHashMap.get(hashMapKey).add(agendamentoVo);
        } else {
            // The key is not there in the HashMap; create a new key-value pair
            List<AgendamentoVo> list = new ArrayList<>();
            list.add(agendamentoVo);
            groupedHashMap.put(hashMapKey, list);
        }
    }

    return groupedHashMap;
}
```

Sending what was grouped to the adapter:

```
mAdapter = new CustomRecyclerViewAdapterFila(listItem, this, this, new CustomItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(View v, int position) {
                            itemclick(position);
                        }
                    });
                    // use this setting to improve performance if you know that changes
                    // in content do not change the layout size of the RecyclerView
                    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
                    layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
                    //mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                    // use a linear layout manager
                    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

In the adapter, mount the grouped layout as follows in the image:

[image]

Then, the adapter array has size 5, the cards are in position 1, 2 and 4. Then for the click, break, for example if clicked on the third card, that is, position 4.

Error:

```
at br.com.sisteplan.evida.atendimento.activities.FilaActivity.itemclick(FilaActivity.java:310)
                                                                                    at br.com.sisteplan.evida.atendimento.activities.FilaActivity.access$500(FilaActivity.java:46)
                                                                                    at br.com.sisteplan.evida.atendimento.activities.FilaActivity$4.onItemClick(FilaActivity.java:291)
                                                                                    at br.com.sisteplan.evida.atendimento.adapters.CustomRecyclerViewAdapterFila$1.onClick(CustomRecyclerViewAdapterFila.java:110)
```

Adapter:

```
private CustomItemClickListener listener;
@NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(
            @NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());

        switch (viewType) {

            case ListItem.TYPE_GENERAL:
                View v1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cell_item_fila, parent,
                        false);
                viewHolder = new GeneralViewHolder(v1);
                break;

            case ListItem.TYPE_DATE:
                View v2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cell_item_date_fila, parent, false);
                viewHolder = new DateViewHolder(v2);
                break;

        }

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {

        switch (viewHolder.getItemViewType()) {

            case ListItem.TYPE_GENERAL:
                final GeneralItem generalItem = (GeneralItem) mDataset.get(position);
                final GeneralViewHolder generalViewHolder= (GeneralViewHolder) viewHolder;
                generalViewHolder.txtTitle.setText(generalItem.getAgendamentoVoGeneral().getPaciente().getNmPaciente());
                generalViewHolder.linearLayoutCard.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    listener.onItemClick(view, generalViewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
                }
            });
                break;

            case ListItem.TYPE_DATE:

                DateItem dateItem = (DateItem) mDataset.get(position);
                DateViewHolder dateViewHolder = (DateViewHolder) viewHolder;
                dateViewHolder.txtTitle.setText(dateItem.getDate());
                // Populate date item data here
                break;
        }
    }
```

ItemClick:

```
private void itemclick(int position) {
    Intent it = new Intent(this, AtendimentoPacienteActivity.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    //CRASH CRASH!!!
    pacienteVo = agendamentoVos.get(position).getPaciente(); //CRASH CRASH!!!
    consultaVo.setDtInicio(UtilDateFormat.dataCorrente());
    consultaVo.setAgendamento(agendamentoVos.get(position));
    bundle.putSerializable(getString(R.string.argument_paciente), pacienteVo);
    bundle.putSerializable(getString(R.string.consulta_bundle), consultaVo);
    it.putExtras(bundle);
    startActivity(it);
}
```

How do I implement the click on item?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your item list is complex one, so it is difficult to handle click based on position but you can always set the TAG with the view and in the onClick method you can get the item with getTag() method and take required action on the item.

```
generalViewHolder.linearLayoutCard.setTag(generalItem);
generalViewHolder.linearLayoutCard.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    listener.onItemClick(view,(GeneralItem)v.getTag());
                }
            });
```

Define :

```
private void onItemClick(View v, GeneralItem generalItem) {
    //do your handling based on generalItem object
}
```

Or alternatively you can set the actual position of the item in your list as TAG value instead of complete item.